# Specific data get Firebase Database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
    var ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in

        self.items.removeAll()

        for chipItem: DataSnapshot in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{

            let chipId: String = chipItem.key

            let titles: DataSnapshot = chipItem.childSnapshot(forPath: "titles")




            for device in titles.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{

                print("Got device: ", device)

                let value: NSDictionary = device.value as! NSDictionary

                let deviceTitle: String = value["title"] as! String
                let deviceId: String = value["id"] as! String

                let deviceState: Bool = chipItem.childSnapshot(forPath: "states/\(deviceId)").value as! Bool

                let newDevice = Device()

                newDevice.title = deviceTitle
                newDevice.chipId = chipId
                newDevice.state = deviceState
                newDevice.id = deviceId

                self.items.append(newDevice)
            }

        }


        self.tableView.reloadData()
```

I don't want to draw all the data. I want to draw certain data for the chipId (such as 123,2). chipId will take the referenced data.
example : chipId = 123 , chipId=2
note : ChipId reference when creating the table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uv9A.png)

Comment: Can you comment what "ref" is?  Where do you define it?  I can help you a lot better.  Also you're screenshot is very vague. Can you post a better one where we can see more of the tree, and we could help you with your reference

Comment: I want to show the top 2 or 123 reference. I updated the photo.

Comment: ChipId reference when creating the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Berk and welcome to StackOverflow.  In order to retrieve specific items in Firebase without getting all the data, you would need to change your Database reference.  Think of the reference as a location in your JSON Tree.  If you want a specific item you would depict that location in your reference when you create it.  For instance.  If I had Users, but only wanted the specifics of one user, I could do this:

```
    let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(user.uid)
```

It's unclear what your reference above is pointing too, but perhaps adding

```
.child("123").child("states").child("002")
```

onto your reference will get you what you need.

Edit:

```
var ref = Database.database().reference().child("123")
```

will get the entire 123 node so you can remove the iterator inside the observe closure and access the child nodes with

```
let titles = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "titles")
```

Coding Example of pulling in data:

```
private func getData() {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("akillipriz-stechome").child("123")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(_ snapshot: DataSnapshot) -> Void in
        for snapshots in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            guard let dict = snapshots.value as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }

            if let states = dict["states"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                print("STATES: \(states)")
            } else {
                print("States Location is Empty or Nil")
            }

            if let titles = dict["titles"] as? [String: AnyObject]  {
                print("TITLES: \(titles)")
            } else {
                print("States Location is Empty or Nil")
            }
        }
    })
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can also note that `.child("123").child("states").child("002")` is the same as `.child("123/states/002")`. It is much easier to read that way.

Comment: Super good answer. I added a little edit for some clarity for the OP. OP - you should probably avoid using arrays to store data as they are hard to work with in NoSQL databases and have limited capability. You may also want to create keys with .childByAutoId and store the chipId as a child node with that.

Comment: for chipItem: DataSnapshot in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{                                                                                                          I need to change this code. data I need to get from the database: chipItem. so I'm pulling all the data in the chipItem I'm going to take only the data under 2 or 123

Comment: for chipItem in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
    }

Comment: When you create your reference what does it look like?

Comment: When creating a chipId reference

Comment: What is main key of your tree that holds all the children?  (The top level of your tree)

Comment: States Location is Empty or Nil

Comment: Thats because we need to know the top level of your tree.  What is the name of the node that all this data falls under in Firebase?

Comment: under the chipId tree. I updated the code @JoshuaHart

Comment: In your screenshot, you show the tree.  The name of that location would be at the very top.

Comment: 2 and 123 very top the tree. I currently have 2 and 123 assets but I only want to see 2 or 123 under tree.

Comment: See picture I added to answer for what I am talking about

Comment: never again empty print code. can you connect with teamviewer? need help. Many thanks for your help

Comment: does:

    `print("Dictionary: \(dict)")`

Have a value?

Comment: Dictionary: ["001": 0, "002": 0] now 123 tree states appear// but only works in this state, does not work when you add the name of the top tree. //     let ref = Database.database().reference().child("123")

Comment: @BerkEylen This *let ref = Database.database().reference().child("123")* is not a correct reference. The reference would be let ref = Database.database().reference(). **child("akillipriz-stechom")** .child("123"). You need to include the parent node *akillipriz-stechom* in the path to the child nodes. See the code this answer as it's accurate.

Comment: From what it looks like from your output, perhaps you had "states" defined as a child in your reference, it should be:
`let ref = Database.database().reference().child("akillipriz-stechome").child("123")`

Comment: this code work: // let ref = Database.database().reference().child("123")
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(_ snapshot: DataSnapshot) -> Void in
            
            self.items.removeAll()


                let chipId: String = snapshot.key
                
                let titles: DataSnapshot = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "titles")
                
// @JoshuaHart